# My toolBar won't show above the webView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I'm trying to add a toolbar to my viewcontroller.

My viewController:

```
-(void)loadView
{
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    self.view = webView;

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.bounds.size.height-50, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50);
    UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(sendAction)];

    UIBarButtonItem *button2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancelAction)];

    [toolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1, nil]];
    [toolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button2, nil]];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
}
```

The toolBar won't show.

Should I avoid:

```
 self.view = webView;
```

And just set the frame of the `self.view` and just add as a subview the webView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a miscalculation in this line:

```
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.bounds.size.height-50, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50);
```

You've set the Y position of the view to be 50 units less than the height of the view.  This would work, however at this point self.view.frame hasn't been correctly calculated and contains a (0,0,0,0) rect.  It would be best to use AutoLayout but a simple/hacky solution would be as follows:

```
CGRect mainScreenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0,mainScreenFrame.size.height-50, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50);
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know why "toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];" wont change the color. Its clear color now and i only recognise the toolBar by its button :\

Comment: So did my answer fix the problem?  If so, accept it as the answer :P.  As for the color problem, try [toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; You might want to also add [toolbar setTranslucent:NO]; if you're using iOS7 and don't want transparency.